# getattr and multiple classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi everyone I have two classes A and B and I want to grab a method from B to use in A.

My code is along the lines of:

```
class A(object):
    __init__(self, args):
         'blah'

    def func2(self, args):
        #method = B.func1(args)
        # method = getattr(B, 'func1')


class B(object):
    __init__(self):
        'do stuff'


    def func1(self, args):
        'Do stuff here'
        return
```

Is there a way to get func1 into A without removing the self attribute from func1?

Neither of the two method calls are working for me and I keep getting a type error

```
TypeError: unbound method func1 must be called with B instance as
first argument (got NoneType instance instead)
```

edit: found my solution

I found the solution to my question. When I passed values from B to A I needed to pass my instance for B as well. So in my init for A

```
class A(object):
    __init__( args, B_arg):
```

And in class B

```
class B(object):


    def passattributes():
         c = A( args, self )
```

Comment: Is `func1` supposed to be used as a method or a function instead? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: fun1 1 is a method which sets the voltage of a channel for a device. The function needs to be called to the channel class which holds the information about each channel in a GUI to dynamically interact and change the voltages the class that func1 belongs to also works as a standalone driver which needs to remain for other programs.

Comment: Why not *split out* the standalone part and reuse that in the method instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that since you're trying to do what you're trying to do, the appropriate thing to do in your case is to define B.func1 as a classmethod, because you don't expect it to require an instance of class B.

```
@classmethod
def func1(cls, args):
   'blah
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an instance of B in the A class:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        'blah'
         self.bInst = B()

    def func2(self, args):
        method = self.bInst.func1('func1')

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        'do stuff'

    def func1(self, args):
        print 'Do stuff here'
        return

aInst = A()
aInst.func2('some arg')
```

Result:

```
Do stuff here
```